# Resizing an array (c)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to resize an array to contain values with length of "newlen". If newlen is less than the original array length, the end of the array is discarded. If newlen is greater, the new integers should be zero. I came up with this function, but when I test it, I get segmentation fault. I also don't know how to add the zeroes to the end, how can I keep track of the index so that I can add int zeroes at the end? I did the first case (where newlen is less than len), but don't know how to do the other case.

Here's the structure for the array:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

My function:

```
array_size( intarr_t* p, unsigned int newlength )

{

  int i,m = 0;

  if (newlength < len) 
        int *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(p->data, (p->newlen)* sizeof *p->data);
    if(tmp)

  {
    for (i; newlength < p->len; i++)
        {  for (m; newlength < p->len; m++)

    {
        p->data[i] = p->data[m];
    }
        }

  }

}
```

Comment: this code is one big mistake, `i` is not initialized, `len` is unknown variable, `tmp` is not used, `newlen` is not used, `double infinite for`... This code should not compile at all

Comment: Make sure `newlength` isn't `1`. better yet make sure it is a power of two

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Before trying to solve runtime errors such as segmentation faults: enable compiler errors and warnings, fix all reported things, and make sure to post your exact code.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not initializing i anywhere before using it in the loop may be it's because of this.

Also for the code

```
for (m; newlength < p->len; m++)
```

where are you re initializing this value for second and other passes of the for loop.Also both the loops are infinite loops.

To implement the second case you can do something like this

```
if(newlength > p->len)
{
    int old_length = p->len;
    p = realloc(p->data, newlength * sizeof(p->data));
    if(p)
        memset(p + old_length,0,(newlength - old_length) * sizeof(p->data));
}
```

Your entire working function will be like this

```
array_size( intarr_t* p, unsigned int newlength ) {
    intarr_t * tmp;
    if(newlength < p->len) {
        tmp = realloc(p->data, newlength * sizeof(p->data)); //realloc will automatically discard elements after new length
        if(tmp) {
            p = tmp;
            p->len = newlength;
        }
    }
    else if(newlength > p->len)
    {
        int old_length = p->len;
        tmp = realloc(p->data, newlength * sizeof(p->data));
        if(tmp){
            p = tmp;
            p->len = newlength;
            memset(p + old_length,0,(newlength - old_length) * sizeof(p->data));//for setting trailing element to 0
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my incomplete function, I forgot to put the main file. I tested this code, it doesn't resize the array to the right len. Maybe because it doesn't add the elements for the first case?

Comment: What is the difference between size that you are getting

Comment: Hmm, I think it's because you're not considering the case where the len is 0. Difference is by 1.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer supplied to `realloc()` (`p->data`) is not changed.

Usage of realloc() normally needs to be something like this

```
tmp = realloc(old_pointer, new_number * sizeof(*tmp));
if (tmp == NULL)
{
      /*   an error occur and old_pointer remains unchanged */
      /*   need to recover */
}
else
{
     old_pointer = tmp;
     length = new_number;
}
```

I'm assuming `tmp` and `old_pointer` are the same type in the above.

Then you can initalise the additional elements of `old_pointer` (assuming the array size is being increased).