# how to resize an array?

Tags: arrays, c

I have to write a function that sorts an array and remove the duplicated and return the value as ordered but out of 9 tests I failed on only one of them when the order > size or order < 0 it should return -1 instead of an actual number but after removing the duplicates the size remained the same on test 4 and I don't know what's the best way to decrease the size of the array or to at least make it work.

I'm allowed to work on lowestPrice function only.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int lowestPrice(int array[], int size, int order){
 
 
int tempArray[size];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tempArray[i] = array[i];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
       
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
       
            if (tempArray[j] < tempArray[i]) {
                int tmp = tempArray[i];
                tempArray[i] = tempArray[j];
                tempArray[j] = tmp;
            }
            
    int j = 0;
    
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        
        if(tempArray[i] != tempArray[i+1])
        {
            tempArray[j] = tempArray[i];                
            j++;    
        } tempArray[j] = tempArray[i+1];
           
        
    }  
       

        if(order > size  || order < 0){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            order--;
     return tempArray[order];        
    }
}
```

```
void oracle(int no, int array[], int size, int order,int expected, int actual){
    printf("Test %d:\n\t\tPrices: {",no);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf(" %d ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n\t\tOrder: %d",order);
    printf("\n\t\tExpected result: %d",expected);
    printf("\n\t\tYour function result: %d",actual);
    printf("\n\t\tStatus: %s\n",expected==actual?"passed":"failed");
}

int main(){
    // oracles
    int tests = 0;
    int testA1[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
    int order1 = 3;
    int res1 = 25000;
    int resA = lowestPrice(testA1,sizeof(testA1)/sizeof(int),order1);
    oracle(1,testA1,sizeof(testA1)/sizeof(int),order1,res1,resA);
    if(res1==resA) tests++;

    int testA2[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
    int order2 = 5;
    int res2 = 29499;
    resA = lowestPrice(testA2,sizeof(testA2)/sizeof(int),order2);
    oracle(2,testA2,sizeof(testA2)/sizeof(int),order2,res2,resA);
    if(res2==resA) tests++;

    int testA3[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
    int order3 = 4;
    int res3 = 29000;
    resA = lowestPrice(testA3,sizeof(testA3)/sizeof(int),order3);
    oracle(3,testA3,sizeof(testA3)/sizeof(int),order3,res3,resA);
    if(res3==resA) tests++;

    int testA4[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
    int order4 = 7;
    int res4 = -1;
    resA = lowestPrice(testA4,sizeof(testA4)/sizeof(int),order4);
    oracle(4,testA4,sizeof(testA4)/sizeof(int),order4,res4,resA);
    if(res4==resA) tests++;
    
     printf("\nYour implementation failed %d test(s).\n\n",(4-tests));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing an array (c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441186/resizing-an-array-c)

Comment: I don't think I can use other functions in this code this function is all I got to work with

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Arrays have a fixed size in C which is set when the array is created and will not change.  The best you can do is

1. Have an array with a fixed size that is "more than enough" and keep track of how much of the array is actually in use with another variable.  When you do this you often have `size` and `capacity` variables (or fields) -- `size` tracks how much of the array is in use and `capacity` tracks its total size.
2. Create a new array with a larger size and copy the elements from the old array.  If your array is on the heap (allocated with malloc/calloc), you may be able to do this in one step with `realloc`.  For static or stack (auto) arrays, you need to create new actual array.

You might combine these two -- have an initial array `capacity` (perhaps allocated with malloc) and when the `size` gets up to `capacity`, create a new array (perhaps with realloc) with a larger `capacity` and copy the data.

---

In your code it looks like you are getting an array as a parameter, along with a `size` parameter which is both the size *and* capacity of the array.  So you can freely decrease the `size` variable and have the effect of decreasing the size of the array, without bothering to track the capacity.  As long as you only decrease `size` (never increase) it will never exceed the capacity.

Comment: don't the j in line 21 works as a capacity?

Comment: You could call it anything you like -- an `int` is an `int`.  It's not at all clear from your code what you are trying to do or what you expect to happen.